# Which solution for GPS analytics (storage and processing) on Heroku/Amazon EMR

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gps, amazon-emr

happy new year and best wishes!
we are collecting a great amount of GPS positions for analytics purpose that we would like to store and process (2-3GB daily data) using Heroku / Amazon services. We are looking for a suitable solution. We initially thought about a system where the data are directly uploaded to Amazon S3, a Worker Dyno constantly tries to process them and puts the GPS positions to a Heroku PostGIS database, then another Worker Dyno would be used on demand to compute analytics output on the fly. We also heard about Amazon Elastic Map Reduce that works directly with raw data in S3 without a PostGIS database. And we need your guidance.
What are your recommendation for this kind of needs for storing and processing data (Heroku add-on, architectures, etc)? What do you think of the 2 alternatives listed above?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give a precise answer as the details of your processing are not clear. Do you need per user analytics, per region analytics, across days etc.

I can point you to some related services:

[Amazon Kinesis](http://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/) - a new service that is targeted at such use cases (Internet of things like). You can PUT your readings from various sources (including directly from the mobile devices) and read them on the server side.

Amazon DynamoDB - NoSQL DB that AWS recently added a geospatial library for it: http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2013/09/dynamodb-geospatial.html
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/09/new-geo-library-for-dynamodb-.html

[RDS with PostgreSQL](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/) - PostgreSQL is very good for GIS calculation and with RDS it is even easier to manage as most of the DBA work that is needed (installation, updates, backup, restore, etc.) are done by RDS service.

S3 - THE place to store your data for batch processing. Note that it is best to have larger files for most processing cases like EMR. You can have a connector that reading the data from Kinesis and storing it into S3 (see GitHub example: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-connectors/tree/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/connectors/s3)

Amazon EMR - this is the cluster management service that makes running jobs like Hadoop jobs much easier. You can find a presentation about using EMR for geospatial analytics in [re:invent BDT201](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/bdt210) and [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRHKJHKL_QU)

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider pre-processing the data to limit the number of redudant records. Most of your positions are likely to be at the same location. In otherwords, the device will be sitting still much of the time.

one approach is to store a new position only if its speed is greater then 0 and the last stored location is also at 0. That way you store only the fist location after the device stops moving.  There will be noise on the GPS speed so you iwll not get rid of every resting position.

Another option would be to store only when a new position is some distance from the previously stored position.

You can always return a result for any requested time by finding the closest record before the requested timestamp.

If you use the range compression, consider setting the required distance at least as large as the expected RMS error for the GPS device, likly to be about 5M minimum, use a longer distance if you can stand it.

Doing the math for distance between Geo locations can be resource expensive, pre-calculate a delta lat lon value to use with incoming positions to speed that up.

Answer (score 0):

EMR launched Kinesis connector so one could process such a dataset using familiar tools in Hadoop Ecosystem. Did you see http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2014/02/process-streaming-data-with-kinesis-and-elastic-mapreduce.html ?